# Dell PERC RAID array how to ignore error

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

We have a Dell PowerEdge R720 with a PERC H710 Raid Array.  It is configured into two disk groups, disk Group 0 which has the OS and the data, and Disk Group 1 which for reasons unknown to me is configured as a RAID 0.  One of the physical disks in Group 1 has failed.  The server always boots into the RAID BIOS.  How can i take Group 1 offline or disable it so that the server can boot?

I have cleared the checkboxes that say to go to BIOS on error.

The real problem is that changes are being stored in the cache that it can't write to the bad disk.  It has the message:

```
There are offline or missing virtual drives with preserved cache.  Please check the cables and ensure that all drives are present.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily the root of my problem, but to get around the immediate problem of not booting, you have to clear the cache in the PERC BIOS.  To clear the cache, you navigate to the screen that has the tree structure of disk groups and virtual disks.  Then navigate by up-arrow until you are on the root of the tree structure, which will be the PERC H710 Mini and not a specific disk group.  Press F2 which gets you to a screen that allows you to manage the cache.  That will allow you to clear the cache.  Exit by hitting ESC and then control-alt-del to reboot.

That allowed the server to boot into its OS normally.

Comment: Knox, thanks for posting how to get around this problem. It worked like a champ for me. The way I got into this mess was I pulled a hot-swappable drive that I *thought* was bad. However, a different drive was bad. So I put this one back in and rebooted, which is when the error popped up. Going through your response let me boot up and see the drive again.